# How do I find technical packages in 16.04 besides command line?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, 16.04

I just upgraded to 16.04.  I'm installing all of the software I use.  Some things that I use were previously in the software center but now cannot be found.  For example, texlive packages (for latex), GDAL (for various GIS programs), etc, used to show up as "technical packages".  Now they are not there at all.

Do I really need to do tedious internet research to figure out what their package names are, so that I can install them via command line?  Or is there some way to make the new software center display them?

Comment: I recommend you use Ubuntu Software (or GNOME Software) instead of of Ubuntu Software Center. USC has been discontinued and is no longer included with Ubuntu starting with 16.04. You only have it because you did an upgrade.

Comment: Right, GNOME software, whatever.  The old software center had technical packages.  The new one doesn't.  How do I find the technical packages besides internet and terminal?

Comment: You may want to try Synaptic as a supplement to Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I misunderstood. Well, according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1562158), GNOME Software is designed to only show GUI apps, not CLI/

Comment: Well, thanks for letting me know that this is indeed deliberate loss of functionality.  Synaptic doesn't seem to be a whole lot better than firefox+bash

Answer (score 1):

You can still install software-center (Ubuntu Software Center) which is not discontinued yet, in fact it got an update in 16.04 release. You can also use synaptic(Synaptic Package Manger) for more advanced options. I use both depending on what i want to do, I removed gnome-software immediately after the update :P

Comment: The OP is on 16.04, where _Ubuntu Software Center_ has been replaced with _Ubuntu Software_.

Comment: I was too tired when I read the question that I didn't understand it. I changed my answer :P